# Why can I not assign type 'Translation' to type 'String' using translator plugin?

Tags: flutter, dart, translation

I am building a translation app and am having difficulties with assigning the final translation to a variable storing that translation, because I want to use it in another place. Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:translator/translator.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: 'Translator',
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Translator'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  TextEditingController textController = TextEditingController();

  var translatedPhrase = "";
  var translator = GoogleTranslator();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold (
        appBar: AppBar(
          centerTitle: true,
          backgroundColor: Colors.green[100],
          title: const Text(
            "What Are You Saying In Spanish?",
            style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 20.0,
            color: Colors.black,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Flexible(
              flex: 1,
              child: Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                height: double.infinity,
                color: Colors.lightBlue,
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    TextField(
                      controller: textController,
                      
                    ),
                    MaterialButton(
                      child: const Text("Translate"),
                      color: Colors.white,
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          // ignore: non_constant_identifier_names
                          translator.translate(textController.text, from: "en", to: "es").then((t) {
                            setState(() {
                              translatedPhrase = t;
                            });
                          });
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Flexible(
              flex: 1,
              child: Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                height: double.infinity,
                color: Colors.grey,
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      translatedPhrase,
                      style: const TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget> [
                        MaterialButton(
                          child: const Icon(Icons.clear),
                          onPressed: () {
                            setState(() {
                              translatedPhrase = "";
                              textController.text = "";
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                        MaterialButton(
                          child: const Icon(Icons.content_copy),
                          onPressed: () {
                            Clipboard.setData(ClipboardData(text: translatedPhrase));
                          },
                        ),
                      ],
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I am getting the error "A value of type 'Translation' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'String'. Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'String'." on line 77 (translatedPhrase = t;). basically, I just would like some help/advice on how to get the Materialbutton working to do the translation function. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `translate` method returns a `Translation` Object so You can not assign it to a String. The Translation object has a property `text`.

So your code should look like this:

```
translator.translate(textController.text, from: "en", to: "es").then((t) {
                            setState(() {
                              translatedPhrase = t.text;
                            });
                          });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following code, hope you got the solution.

```
   GoogleTranslator translator = GoogleTranslator();
              await translator
                  .translate(textController.text, from: 'en', to: 'es')
                  .then((value) {
                translatedPhrase = value.toString();
                setState(() {});
              });
```